# php jquery remote validate problem

Tags: php, jquery, validation

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("captcha", function(value, element)  {
       $.ajax({ url: "verifyCap.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "txtCaptcha="+value,
                success:        
                     function(msg) { 
                         if(msg == "true")
                               return true;  // already exists
                         return false; 
                        }
                  });
    },"");
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        title: "required",
        contactname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        comment: "required",
        txtCaptcha:{
            required: true,
            captcha: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        contactname: "Please enter your contact name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        comment: "Please enter your system requierment",
        txtCaptcha: {
            required:"Please enter verification code",
            captcha: "The verification code is incorrect"
        }
    }
});
});
```

My verifyCap.php

```
<?php
 session_start ();
 if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET")
  die ( "You can only reach this page by posting from the html form" );
 if (($_GET ["txtCaptcha"] == $_SESSION ["security_code"]) && (! empty ( $_GET ["txtCaptcha"] ) && ! empty ( $_SESSION ["security_code"] ))) {
   echo  "true";
 } else {
     echo "false";
}
 ?>
```

My problem might due to the response format it is not true or false, but i print out whole verifyCap code. Anyone can help?

Comment: Is this the only validation you are doing with your form? Or is there other server-side validation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ajax request does an get by default instead of a post. Change:

```
if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST")
```

to

```
if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET")
```

besides that, do not use `$_REQUEST` to get your data. Use `$_GET` instead.

You could also add some settings your ajax request:

```
   type: "POST",
   data: "your params here",
```

Comment: **This** AJAX request uses `GET`, but not all requests do. You can set it to `POST` too. You should edit your answer to reflect that, as it is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Okay i change both to GET still the same problem

Comment: @Clement: I was probably editing my post while your were commenting :)

Comment: It won't validate the txtcaptcha

Comment: <?php
session_start ();
if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET")
 die ( "You can only reach this page by posting from the html form" );
if (($_GET ["txtCaptcha"] == $_SESSION ["security_code"]) && (! empty ( $_GET ["txtCaptcha"] ) && ! empty ( $_SESSION ["security_code"] ))) {
 $valid = true;
} else {
 $valid = false;
}
echo $valid;

?>

Comment: Did you pass the value of your txtCaptcha in your ajax request? If you haven't, that's probably the problem

Comment: Hi thanks, i have edited my code above, I am able to alert true or false correctly, but the error message won't disappear the form can't pass through even return true

Comment: in your ajax request you have a `return false` right after the `return true`. Javavscript (unlike php) won't stop executing the script after a return, therefore following the return false all the time. move the `return false` to the `} else {`.

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the whole verifyCap.php code because your PHP isn't interpreted by your web server.

In your verifyCap.php you are using the short tag notation (`<? //code ?>`).
Not all server uses this php extension, and it is considered deprecated. If your webserver doesn't use this extension, then your code is considered as an XML document, as XML document always start with `<? <!-- some XML here --> ?>`.

Use `<?php //code ?>` and your problem should be fixed.

Also, following @XpertEase answer isn't a bad idea either.

Edit: More info on PHP short tags [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) (via @XpertEase)

Comment: that should help too indeed. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: hi i have change it to <?php still getting the same problem